# Connection Refused: curl <ec2 public dns>:8080

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port

NOTE* there are a lot of question with similar titles but they either (1) do not have any good answer or (2) are not related to the following issue.

I am trying to run a simple chat/messaging demo via node.js on my Ubuntu ec2 instance running apache2. The application works great on my local machine but I am having some trouble with the setup on my server.

I am trying to listen to port 8080 but upon executing:

```
$ curl <ec2 public dns>:8080
```

I can the error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <ec2 public dns> port 8080: Connection refused
```

I went through the default troubleshooting steps:

(1) Quadruple check to make sure I am allowing incoming connections on port 8080 in my ec2 security group.

(2) Check my ufw firewall to make sure port 8080 is enabled:

```
ubuntu@ip-000-00-00-000:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I am newer to all of the concepts mentioned in this post so I may be missing something simple.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try serverfault or maybe superuser.

Comment: If you run the curl command on the server, like `curl localhost:8080` does it work?

Comment: it does not work but I found the answer to my question: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/628321/cant-curl-curl-7-failed-to-connnect-connection-refused) I realized that port 8080 wasn't listening for anything.

So I ran

```
node chat.js
```

Which somewhere in the code called .listen(8080). Then upon calling curl, it worked.